# Как записать событие в Cookie

Tags: javascript, cookie

На странице, при нажатии на одну из кнопок, выполняется событие:

```
<button onclick="getController().volume-=0.1">скрутить звук</button>
<button onclick="getController().volume+=0.1">добавить звук</button>
```

Подскажите, как при этом можно писать в куки: 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 если пользователь повышает звук, либо минусовать если понижает звук. При этом проверяя лимит для значения volume: 0.0 - 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button onclick="getController().volume-=0.1;storeVolume(getController().volume);">скрутить звук</button>
<button onclick="getController().volume+=0.1;storeVolume(getController().volume);">добавить звук</button>
```

```js
function storeVolume(vol) {
setCookie("volume",vol);
}

function getCookie(name) {
  var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(
    "(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"
  ));
  return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined;
}

function setCookie(name, value, options) {
  options = options || {};

  var expires = options.expires;

  if (typeof expires == "number" && expires) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + expires * 1000);
    expires = options.expires = d;
  }
  if (expires && expires.toUTCString) {
    options.expires = expires.toUTCString();
  }

  value = encodeURIComponent(value);

  var updatedCookie = name + "=" + value;

  for (var propName in options) {
    updatedCookie += "; " + propName;
    var propValue = options[propName];
    if (propValue !== true) {
      updatedCookie += "=" + propValue;
    }
  }

  document.cookie = updatedCookie;
}
```

https://learn.javascript.ru/cookie

Comment: Андрей, благодарю, за материал к прочтению. Сейчас срабатывает, но принимает значение как: `NaN0.10.10.10.10.1` Изначально: `NaN`, после запуска видео к `NaN` приписываются `цифры`

Comment: Попробуйте исправленный вариант

Comment: Андрей, супер :) и все цифры в допустимых пределах хранятся.

Answer (score -2):

Почитайте про свойство [setcookie](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php) (PHP).